# Z-index not working with background-clip:text and pseudo element

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to dynamically change the color of a button on hover using a sliding motion. Everything works correctly except for the fact that the pseudo element covers the actual link text. The text itself is made transparent and I am using a background clip to achieve the dynamic slide.

I made some tests and if the text has a color the pseudo element doesn't cover it. However, **when using the background to fill the text, the pseudo element (or at lest its background) seems to skip the z-index and always sit above the background of the actual element.**

I am now out of ideas and asking to the internet for help

```
<div class="link-container">
  <a class="link link1" href="/projects">CHECK MY WORK</a>
  <a class="link2" href="/contact" style="text-align: end;">GET IN TOUCH</a>
</div>
```

```
.link-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      .link1 {
       ...same as link 2
        }
      }

      .link2 {
        z-index: 0;
        margin: 2rem 0;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: transparent;
        border: 5px solid black;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
        background-clip: text;
        background-size: 200%;
        background-position: left;

        &:after {
          z-index: -1;
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: black;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. CSS on its own, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little.

Comment: z-index:1; make z-index positive value

Comment: Plesse show your HTML code also.

Comment: Make z -index of  pseudo element positive @Simone

Comment: just added the HTML, is that better?

Comment: remove z-ondex from link2 and link1